# Python: why aren’t strings being internalized if they are received from ints by using str()?

Tags: python, string, integer

```py
a = "123"
b = "12" + "3"
c = str(100+20+3)

print(a is b, b is c)
```

Why would the output be ‘False’ in the second case?

Comment: why do you think *anything should happen here at all*? A better question is *why do you think the output should be `True` in the first case*? Python makes no such guarantees. these are all implementation details

Comment: In Python object constructor always creates a new object, as you know `is` checks object id identity, so even if their values are identical, they are two separate objects in memory.

Comment: @UbaydulloIbrohimov no, a constructor doesn't always create a new object. try `str("abc")  is "abc"`. But the *crucial* point is that these are all implementation details that shouldn't be relied on. The OP seems to understand what the `is` operator is for

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, `str("abs")` - it is not constructing anything, because the value that you are giving is already a string. Try `str(123) is '123'`.

Comment: @UbaydulloIbrohimov right, which is an example **where the constructor doesn't create a new object**. I didn't say *it always returns an existing object*. You claimed *it always returns a new object*, which is *false*, as is trivially demonstrated by my example. It is also trivial to define a type, `class Foo:` e.g. with `def __str__(self): return self.whataever` which **always** returns the same object, so `str(Foo()) is str(Foo())` is also not going to create a new object

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `is` operator is to say whether two variables reference the same object. The only scenario where this is *guaranteed* is when they have been explicitly set up that way.

```
>>> a = "random string"
>>> b = a
>>> a is b
True
```

There are other scenarios wher  Python might notice that two unrelated variables refer to the same value, and have them pass this test; but that is not guaranteed, merely an implementation detail which should not, and indeed cannot, be relied on.

```
>>> c = 1
>>> d = 1
>>> c is d
True  # or not
```

Answer (score -1):

In Python, `is` operator is called the identity operator. Python interpreter assigns each object in the computer's memory a unique identification number (`id`). The identity operator returns true if the `id()` of two objects is the same else false. So, `is` operator tests if two variables point to the same object and not if two variables have the same value.

To illustrate

```
print("a:", a, type(a), id(a), a is b, a is c)
print("b:", b, type(b), id(b), b is a, b is c)
print("c:", c, type(c), id(c), c is a, c is a)  # notice the difference in id(c)
```

Use `==` operator to test if two values are the same.

Comment: the OP already knows what `is` does, that isn't the quesiton